# How to append to a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, append, appendchild

I have the following nested dictionary:

```
d = {'A':{'a':1}, 'B':{'b':2}}
```

I want to add values to `d` without overwriting.

So if I want to append the value ['A', 'b', 3] the dictionary should read:

```
d = {'A':{'a':1, 'b':3}, 'B':{'b':2}}
```

`d['A'].append({'b':3})` errors with:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

I don't know what the nested dictionary will be in advance. So saying:

```
d['A'] = {'a':1, 'b':3}
```

will not work for my case as I am "discovering/calculating" the values as the script runs.

Thanks

Comment: You don't "append" to dictionary. You set key with value. `d['A']['b'] = 3`

Comment: @RealRageDontQuit: Does "without overwriting" mean that if d['A'] already contains a 'b' entry, you don't want to update with the new value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, `append` is only for lists, not dictionaries.

This should do what you want:

`d['A']['b'] = 3`

Explanation: When you write `d['A']` you are getting another dictionary (the one whose key is A), and you can then use another set of brackets to add or access entries in the second dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [the `update` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
d['A'].update({'b':3})
```